# Github STAR button on repository page

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any way to add star button to the promotional page of the repository just like there is facebook like and Google Plus' +1 button?

Comment: Not easily. Using the API you'd have to make this call `https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository` but it requires authentication so first you'd have to get an oath token (`https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations`)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ghbtns.com/)

Comment: @KamranAhmed: Great, posted as an answer so others can find it easily

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I use GitHub buttons, which you can find [here](http://ghbtns.com/)

[image]

Comment: The problem with ghbtns.com is that when you click on the star button it doesn't actually star the project.  It just takes you to the GitHub page.  Then you have to click the button again.  This will be confusing for many users.

Comment: But there used to be official buttons where you had to click only once to star a project, right? Were they discontinued?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the unofficial buttons provided by:
https://buttons.github.io (more customization options).

[image]

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/ntkme/github-buttons